# Detecting circles in an image using laplacian

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, computer-vision, gaussian

I'm trying detect the disk and cup in the back of an eye (fundus) to calculate certain things later on. So here is an image of the eye:

[image]

I'm just trying to detect the disk, or the larger yellow-ish circle on the right side of the image, and the cup, or the smaller yellow circle inside that first circle, using OpenCV and python so I can eventually perform certain calculations.

So far, I've tried to use laplacian filtering to make the circle more prominent.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pylab import *

# loading image
img0 = cv2.imread('01_g.jpg',)

# converting to gray scale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img0, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# remove noise
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(3,3),0)

# convolute with proper kernels
laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img,cv2.CV_64F)
sobelx = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=5)  # x
sobely = cv2.Sobel(img,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=5)  # y
magnitude = sqrt(sobelx**2+sobely**2)

plt.subplot(2,2,1),plt.imshow(img,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Original'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.subplot(2,2,2),plt.imshow(laplacian,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Laplacian'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.subplot(2,2,3),plt.imshow(sobelx,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Sobel X'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.subplot(2,2,4),plt.imshow(sobely,cmap = 'gray')
plt.title('Sobel Y'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

This is the result I got:
[image]

As you can see, the laplacian filter didn't help at all-- in fact, the cup and disk aren't even visible. The sobelx and sobely at least gave some outline of the outer circle (disk)

I also have tried the absolute value of the laplacian:

```
final = np.absolute(laplacian)
plt.imshow(final, cmap = 'gray')
plt.show()
```

and I got this result:

[image]

I have also tried applying the [Difference of Gaussians method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_Gaussians) using this code:

```
#difference of gaussians

blur1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(3,3),1)
blur2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),1.1)
difference = blur2 - blur1
plt.imshow(difference, cmap = 'gray')
plt.show()
```

But this also doesn't get me anywhere. I would really appreciate some help on how I might go about detecting the cup and disk in this image.

Comment: I think the imshow command automatically scales the image so that the highest value is white and the lowest is black. Since you have a very strong edge around your circular image, it will be hard to see the weaker edges inside

Comment: @ShalinShah try to imshow the absolute values instead of the signed values of the laplacian

Comment: @HugoRune I cropped the image so the image is now only the inside part and the very strong edge is gone....but the output didn't change at all

Comment: @Micka imshow-ing the absolute value made the image become darker but it didn't improve the visibility of the disk. I placed a screenshot of this in my question.

Comment: if you scale and convert to unsigned type you'll get a better visualization because 0 will be black and not some gray

Comment: @Micka do you know what size scaling the image to will provide the best result? And should I just use cv2.resize to scale it?

Comment: no, don't rescale the image. scale the pixel values of the sobel to fit to an unsigned data type or float range

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114771/discussion-between-shalin-shah-and-micka).

Comment: Hi, did you find my answer below useful? Any comments are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @dhanushka I did not end up using your approach to find the cup and disk, but your answer definitely helped me find a good approach, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Previous MSER approach as shown fails to find a circular blob, though it highlights the region. So I tried [Difference-of-Gaussians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_Gaussians)(DoG) for blob detection, and it gives good results. You can experiment with the gaussian kernel sizes and their sigmas. Note that I've downsampled the image and removed the vessel structures by dilation prior to applying the DoG. Thresholding the DoG image gives you the blobs.

Also I noticed that the region you are interested in is the global maximum of the image (it may not be so for a different image). May be you can combine this knowledge as well to your algorithm.

DoG

[image: dog]

Thresholded DoG

[image: thresh]

Global Max

[image: max]

Code (c++) for Dog approach

```
Mat im = imread("8Lzuq.jpg", 0);
Mat dw;

pyrDown(im, dw);
pyrDown(dw, dw);
pyrDown(dw, dw);

Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(7, 7));
morphologyEx(dw, dw, CV_MOP_DILATE, kernel);

Mat g1, g2, dog, bw;
GaussianBlur(dw, g1, Size(31, 31), 21, 21);
GaussianBlur(dw, g2, Size(65, 65), 31, 31);
dog = g1 - g2;
normalize(dog, dog, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX);

threshold(dog, bw, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);

Point mx;
minMaxLoc(dw, NULL, NULL, NULL, &mx);

circle(dw, mx, 20, Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);
```

**MSER approach**

I tried downsampling the color image, dilating it, then detecting [MSER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximally_stable_extremal_regions)s in individual channels. The result looks good though it doesn't outline the disk as a perfect circle.

Blue channel:

[image: b][image: bmser]

Green channel:

[image: g][image: gmser]

Red channel:

[image: r][image: rmser]

Detecting MSERs in the color image didn't work well.

Code in c++

```
Mat im = imread("8Lzuq.jpg");
Mat dw;

pyrDown(im, dw);
pyrDown(dw, dw);
pyrDown(dw, dw);

Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(7, 7));
morphologyEx(dw, dw, CV_MOP_DILATE, kernel);

Mat ch[3];
split(dw, ch);

MSER mser;
vector<vector<Point>> regions;

mser(ch[2], regions);
Mat regionsMat = Mat::zeros(dw.rows, dw.cols, CV_8U);

for (size_t i = 0; i < regions.size(); i++)
{
    for (Point pt: regions[i])
    {
        uchar& val = regionsMat.at<uchar>(pt);
        if (val > 0)
        {
            val += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            val = 1;
        }
    }

}

imwrite("reg.jpg", regionsMat*50);
```